# How to hook up Angular search with other components?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a search bar into my Angular app that will filter data coming from an API. I am using the following tutorial: [Angular Search](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/forms/search/#remote)

Here is my API call:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'players',
  templateUrl: './players.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./players.component.css']
})

export class PlayersComponent {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscriptions.push(this.webService.getPlayers().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.player_list = response;
    }));
  }
}
```

This returns an array like:

[image]

As the tutorial states, I first created the search bar:

```html
<!-- Search Bar -->

<input type="search" class="searchBar" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Search for a player...">
```

I then added the filter into my existing `*ngFor`:

```html
<!-- Before -->
<div *ngFor="let player of player_list | paginate: config">

<!-- Adding filter -->
<div *ngFor="let player of player_list | paginate: config | filter: searchText">
```

In my terminal, I then ran:

```
ng generate pipe filter
```

And this created 2 new files:

```
app
 |___ filter.pipe.spec.ts
 |___ filter.pipe.ts
```

I then added in this code to `filter.pipe.ts`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {

    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchText) {
      return items;
    }
    searchText = searchText.toLocaleLowerCase();

    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

But when I go back into my browser, I get this error message:

[image]

How do I get the `players.component.ts` to read from `filter.pipe.ts`. I have tried importing it like:

```js
// players.component.ts file

import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';

...

constructor(public webService: WebService, public filterPipe: FilterPipe) {}
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: Did you import FilterPipe in the module file? `declarations: [..., FilterPipe ],` ?

Comment: @NouiNou yeah it is included there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly saying that searchText does not exist on PlayersComponent. You need to define searchText on PlayersComponent.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'players',
  templateUrl: './players.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./players.component.css']
})

export class PlayersComponent {

    searchText = '';  // This is missing..

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscriptions.push(this.webService.getPlayers().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.player_list = response;
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean still you are seeing that error?

Comment: what @DevangPatel said is that you don't have a `searchText` property in the `PlayersComponent` class not the pipe.

Comment: Then please share your code on stackblitz.

Comment: @DevangPatel I have taken your approach and got some kind of solution. I added the code `searchText!: string;` and this took away the error but I can not filter my data properly but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: In this case, you need to debug in the filter pipe what is returning from there. You can share code on stackblitz if want me to look.

Comment: Hi @DevangPatel I got the code working, I am new to Angular and didn't understand pipe and how they worked but I figured it out with help from you solution